# как использовать внутренний innerHTML

Tags: javascript

как использовать внутренний innerHTML

Comment: А разве есть внешний `innerHTML`?

Comment: Укажите конкретную проблему, которую можно решить или объяснить.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const element = document.getElementById('test');

function addValue(){
element.innerHTML += ' addValue';
}

function newValue(){
element.innerHTML = ' newValue';
}
```

```html
  <div id="test">
       Какой-то текст.
  </div>

<button onclick="newValue()">Заменить на новое значение</button>
<button onclick="addValue()">Добавить новое значение</button>
```